# Convert full GIT ref to unambiguous short ref

Tags: git

I have a bunch of GIT references obtained from:

```
git for-each-ref refs --format='%(refname)'
```

They are in the form `refs/heads/branchName`.
How can I convert each to their unambiguous short name? The same as I would get from:

```
git for-each-ref refs --format='%(refname:short)'
```

There may be branches and tags with the same name. I need the full ref for `git update-ref` but would like to print more Porcelain style messages if possible.

Comment: `git for-each-ref refs --format='%(refname)' | xargs git rev-parse --abbrev-ref`

Comment: @PetSerAl Post answers as *answers*, not comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref` to convert given reference to short non-ambiguous form. For example:

```
git for-each-ref refs --format='%(refname)' | xargs git rev-parse --abbrev-ref
```